How to use WayVNC in virtual mode instead of service/console mode on a headful Pi?
I set up a new Pi5 at a remote location and plugged it into an old DVI monitor + kbd + mouse in case anyone needs watch the boot process. Setup is default Wayland + WayVNC. Now that I'm away, RealVNC Viewer (on Windows 10) only allows me to connect to the console (1280x1024 attached monitor) rather than a virtual desktop of my choosing (e.g. 1920x1080 to match my local monitor). Is this possible without removing the monitor on the Pi (e.g. going headless)? If so, how?
I've tried:

In /boot/firmware/config.txt, set display_auto_detect=0 -> this just gives me a blank screen when connecting VNC
In ~/.config/wayfire.ini, added output:headless-1 section with headless_width|headless_height values
In ~/.config/wayfire.ini, added output:headless-2 section with mode = 1920x1080
Tried restarting wayvnc specifying --output=headless-1|2 but first it complained that WAYLAND_DISPLAY was not set in the environment
So I tried setting the variable with export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=headless-1 (and also headless=2) but then I get...

ERROR: ../src/main.c: 529: Failed to connect to WAYLAND_DISPLAY="headless-1"
ERROR: ../src/main.c: 530: Ensure wayland is running with that display name
ERROR: ../src/main.c: 1876: Failed to initialise wayland


I noticed at some point (maybe after display_auto_detect=0 was set) raspi-config gave me the option to select VNC resolution, but once connected, I was still stuck at 1280x1024

I'm at a loss. What do I need to do to have BOTH a working display on the Pi-attached monitor AND a higher resolution display for VNC connections?
In case it matters, wlr-randr returns:
HDMI-A-2 "Dell Inc. DELL 1704FPT Y429954JBEU6 (HDMI-A-2)"
Physical size: 340x270 mm
Enabled: yes
Modes:
   720x400 px, 70.082001 Hz
   640x480 px, 59.939999 Hz
   640x480 px, 75.000000 Hz
   800x600 px, 60.317001 Hz
   800x600 px, 75.000000 Hz
   1024x768 px, 60.004002 Hz
   1024x768 px, 75.028999 Hz
   1152x864 px, 75.000000 Hz
   1280x1024 px, 75.025002 Hz
   1280x1024 px, 60.020000 Hz (preferred, current)
Position: 0,0
Transform: normal
Scale: 1.000000

I'm at the point where I'm ready to try a different VNC client or just switch back to X11, but I'd rather get familiar with Wayland.

You appear to be complaining that WayVNC mirrors your screen!
This is how it is designed to work.
If you want to specify a different resolution don't connect a monitor and you can set resolution in Screen Layout Editor Layout/Screens/NOOP-1/Screen Configuration. This offers a number of preset options (although 1920x1024 is not offered).
Mine is currently set in ~/.config/wayfire.ini to:-
[output:NOOP-1]
mode = 1920x1080
position = 0,0
transform = normal

The output:headless-1 settings you mention are not present, I normally use the Screen Layout Editor so I don't have to remember the details of wayfire.ini.
The alternative is NOT to use the standard VNC setup but create a virtual screen (this is how most VNC clients work).

Create a virtual screen... YES! IIRC, in x11 I could select whether RealVNC would connect to the console or a virtual desktop. Don't know what I'm missing to create that virtual desktop for WayVNC. Is going headless the only option?

@MJA I am still getting my mind around the new system (which seems to be poorly documented) BUT it may not be possible; as I understand it each process is independent and cannot share data.

Correct answer marked above. With the monitor disconnected, I could set the VNC resolution to whatever I wanted (output was NOOP-1). Additionally, I reconnected the monitor while the VNC session was connected, and the VNC screen resolution immediately changed to the 1280x1024 of the monitor. I will keep my eye out for alternative solutions.
